# show month number instead of month name on symfony2 formbuilder

Tags: symfony

It might be ridiculous quesion, but I can't find the way with googling.

I am making form like this.
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder($searchTime)

```
     ->add('date','date',array(
            "property_path" => false,
           'years' => $years,
            'data' => new \Datetime()
```

but it shows month select box as name such as jun,july,aug

however I want to show number here 6,7,8 ....

How can I make it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's worth a try to specify a `format`, as the reference says:

```
$builder->add('date', 'date', array(
    'widget' => 'choice',
    'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    // ...
));
```

The reference says, that if your `widget` is `choice` and you specify the `format` then the selects will be rendered in the order of the format. Maybe the select format is also will be adjusted to the format pattern.

(The month without leading zeros would be: yyyy-M-dd)